uPickle ReadWriter for joda DateTime fails
For a project, i need JSON representation for a org.joda.time.DateTime. For JSON, i use uPickle. As there is no implicit ReaderWriter[DateTime], i have to write it myself. After googleing around, i came up with the following code:
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat
import upickle.default._

object DateTimeRW:
  val fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()
  given ReadWriter[DateTime] = readwriter[ujson.Value].bimap[DateTime](
    dt => fmt.print(dt),
    dtstr => fmt.parseDateTime(dtstr.str)
  )

val dt = DateTime.now()
val jsonDateString = write(dt)
val dt2: DateTime = read(dt.toString)

It fails. I do not even understand the errors:
missing argument for parameter evidence$5 of method write in trait Api: (implicit evidence$5: upickle.default.Writer[org.joda.time.DateTime]): String

missing argument for parameter evidence$3 of method read in trait Api: (implicit evidence$3: upickle.default.Reader[T]): T

It seems that my implementation is wrong, but i cannot detect any syntactical error like a missing argument. Google finds NO answers for the error descriptions. Can someone help?

This compiles and works:
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat
import upickle.default._
import upickle.default.ReadWriter.join

object DateTimeRW:
    val fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()
    given ReadWriter[DateTime] = readwriter[ujson.Value].bimap[DateTime](
        x => fmt.print(x),
        dtstr => fmt.parseDateTime(dtstr.str)
    )
import DateTimeRW.given_ReadWriter_DateTime

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val dt = DateTime.now()
  val jsonDateString = write(dt)
  println(jsonDateString)
  val dt2: DateTime = read(jsonDateString)
  println(dt2)
}

sbt:
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.4.2"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "ScalaStuff"
  )

libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "4.0.0-RC1"
libraryDependencies += "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.12.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "2.32.0"


This one compiles and works as well (it is based on this example):
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat
import upickle.default._
import upickle.default.ReadWriter.join

//object DateTimeRW:
//    val fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()
//    given ReadWriter[DateTime] = readwriter[ujson.Value].bimap[DateTime](
//        x => fmt.print(x),
//        dtstr => fmt.parseDateTime(dtstr.str)
//    )
//import DateTimeRW.given_ReadWriter_DateTime

object DateTimeRw2:
    val fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()
    implicit val rw: ReadWriter[DateTime] = upickle.default.readwriter[String].bimap[DateTime](
         x => fmt.print(x),
         dtAsStr => DateTime.parse(dtAsStr, fmt)
    )
import DateTimeRw2.*

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val dt = DateTime.now()
  val jsonDateString = write(dt)
  println(jsonDateString)
  val dt2: DateTime = read(jsonDateString)
  println(dt2)
}

Note that I didn't have to be so explicit in my import as I've been in the other case.
Unfortunately, I have to admit, I don't know enough about the compiler to explain you why exactly in the other case you need to be explicit in importing the given (just import DateTimeRw.* doesn't do it), and why when using the implicit val, it seems to work. I probably need to brush up my knowledge on how the compiler resolves these.
You can assign your own name if you don't like the compiler default:
object DateTimeRW:
    val fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()
    given rw: ReadWriter[DateTime] = readwriter[ujson.Value].bimap[DateTime](
        x => fmt.print(x),
        dtstr => fmt.parseDateTime(dtstr.str)
    )
import DateTimeRW.rw

Note:

read(dt.toString)

This is incorrect. You want: read(jsonDateString).

Thank you a lot! The missing import was the problem.
I will consider the more idiomatic solution with upickle.default.readwrite.

See also this: https://alexn.org/blog/2022/05/11/implicit-vs-scala-3-given/ for a deeper dive given vs implicit

The wrong parameter in the definition of dt2 is clear.
The import with DateTimeRw.* should fail as in Scala the wildcard is _, not * :-)

Actually, in Scala 3 they moved back to * instead of _.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/wildcards.html says otherwise.
In Scala 3.0, * is available as a type parameter placeholder.
In Scala 3.2, * is deprecated in favor of _. A -rewrite option is available to rewrite one to the other.
In Scala 3.3, * is removed again, and all type parameter placeholders will be expressed with _.

Wrong context. https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/imports.html confirms you. Sry.

No worries, thank you for point that out! I changed the code.

@ChristianH.Kuhn this works as well import DateTimeRW.given instead of specifying a name.
